# Generating mutilple plots in one gnuplot window

Tags: c, gnuplot

I've got many files containing data and I want to plot all the data in a single gnuplot window. I'm using C. My current code is

```
gnuplotPipe = popen ("gnuplot -persistent", "w");
//loop starts for each file
system("gnuplot -p -e \"plot 'file_variable'""); // skipping some steps to generate variable file name
//end loop
fclose(gnuplotPipe);
```

It is generating graphs in individual windows. How to combine all of them in one?

Files format are like

```
2 0.000003
2 0.000002
2 0.000002
```

in `file_2.txt`

```
3 0.000001
3 0.000000
3 0.000001
```

in `file_3.txt`

```
.
.
.
```

in `file_n.txt` n is between 3 and 98

```
99 0.004800
99 0.004752
99 0.004716
```

in `file_99.txt`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You forgot to include your question.

Comment: I though it would be obvious from title but thanks for mentioning, I am adding current code too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually the `plot` command can take multiple file names at once as argument and plot their data in a single graph.

```
plot 'file_1', 'file_2', .... 'file_n'
```

So you can construct a sting containing all the file names and then pass it in the `system()` function.

It will be something like this.

```
char *arg = "gnuplot -p -e \"plot";
//Start a loop
//Generate your variable file name
strcat(arg, generated_filename);
//End loop
gnuplotPipe = popen ("gnuplot -persistent", "w");
system(arg);
fclose(gnuplotPipe);
```

Just make sure the generated file names are composed into a string like this- **" 'filename',"**

(A white space followed by a single quote, file name, single quote and finally a comma)

You can learn more about plotting multiple files in a single graph in the last example here in this [site](http://alvinalexander.com/technology/gnuplot-charts-graphs-examples). You can also format your graph if you want as shown in the example there.